# MDX Scope statement some issue

Tags: sql, mdx, msbi

I am struggling with SSAS as this is the first time I play around with the `SCOPE` statement.

I am trying to build the following:

```
SCOPE(YEAR([Measures].[End Date]));
IF THIS IS [Measures].[End Date] NULL THEN this = 2014 END IF;
END SCOPE;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will be easier for contributors to help you if you explain the problem encountered.

Answer (score 0):

MDX isn't a SQL-like language. Its syntax and semantic is very different from regular DBMS query languages. There are no NULL values in MDX, they are called Empty values. We can only guess what do you want from your code. I suggest you want to set 2014 as Default member. If so, see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174822(v=sql.105).aspx